# Como remover um pod e apagar tudo relacionado a ele

Tags: servidor

Tenho alguns `pods`, e reparei que so apagar o `pod` em si ainda não
liberava recursos computacionais necessários, pois tenho um cluster com pouco recurso.

Usando o comando:

```
kubectl delete pod xxxxx
```

O mesmo é removido, mas ainda tem o service, então apago também:

```
kubectl delete svc xxxxx
```

Minha dúvida é, o que mais posso apagar relacionado a esse `pod` criado?

Comment: Fiz uma troca provisória de tags, para reorganização. Sobre o escopo, vide discussões mais recentes no Meta sobre containerização. Este fechamento não invalida a postagem e nem impede localização na pesquisa tampouco votos futuros tanto na pergunta quanto resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existem diversas maneiras de criar recursos dentro do kubernetes, dependendo da forma utilizado pode ser mais simples ou complicado deletar as dependências criadas.

Caso tenha criado cada item manualmente, eles teriam uma correlação muito baixa e o kubernetes possui dezenas de recursos possíveis, alguns critérios podem ser levantados como nome porém para evitar deleções indevidas seria bom deletar na ordem criada.

Para evitar esse contratempos futuramente, seguem algumas sugestões:

1. Use os manifestos em yaml para controlar todos os recursos criados, apartir deles será possível efetuar a deleção apartir de um comando:

```bsh
kubectl delete -f template.yml
```

2. Use namespaces pois nesse cenário será mais fácil deletar tudo aquilo dentro do mesmo namespace:

```
kubectl delete all --all -n NOME_DO_NAMESPACE
```

Comment: Por que essa resposta foi rebaixada é um mistério. É mais correta. Os diversos objetos da API não possuem relação direta entre si, como se fosse um banco de dados relacional. A regra, de fato, é: ser vc não criou, não precisa remover. Por isso é importante manter os manifestos de tudo que você cria. Considere-os como a fonte da verdade do seu cluster. É possível remover tudo que você criou dentro do namespace rapidamente simplesmente apagando o namespace. Usar helm tb ajuda, pq ele controla todo manifesto que ele mesmo instalou.

Answer (score 1):

Recursos que podem estar associado ao pod:

- **service accounts:** kubectl get sa xxxx
- **deployments:** kubectl get deployment xxxx

Caso você tenha criado esses pods usando deployment, verifique também por replica sets:

- **replica sets:** kubectl get rs xxxx